# Using CFSchedule to write to a log file

Tags: coldfusion

I am having a hard time figuring out how to use cfschedule and hope someone can help get me unstuck.

I can schedule a task fine. The Admin portal indicates that the task has run, but I don't see that anything has happened.

```
<cfschedule
   action="update"
   task="update_printer_status"
   operation="HTTPRequest"
   startDate="03/26/2018"
   startTime="12:00 PM"
   url="http://localhost:8000/source/update_status.cfm"
   interval="1800" />
```

For testing purposes, I am just trying to get it to save the date/time it runs into a log file. But the log file is empty. Here's my log file.

```
<!--- Read in existing contents of file --->    
<cffile 
        action="read"
        file = "c:\temp\update_log.txt" 
        variable = "file_contents"
    >
<!--- Set additional content ---> 
<cfset br = chr(13) & chr(10) />
<cfset date="#DateFormat(Now())#, #TimeFormat(Now())#">

<!--- Write string back to  log file ---> 
<cfset update_string="#file_contents##br#Update initiated: #date#">
<cfscript> 
    FileWrite("update_string", "#update_string#"); 
    ustr = FileRead("update_string"); 
    FileWrite("c:\temp\update_log.txt", "#ustr#"); 
</cfscript>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: There's a couple assumptions here. 1) That your log file script is actually `update_status.cfm` 2) That it's running correctly.  One of the things you can do is actually run the url `http://localhost:8000/source/update_status.cfm` on your browser.  Check to see if there's any errors.  Another is the check the `Save output to file` on CFADMIN for the task, and see what's outputted.

Comment: Thanks, Yes that is the correct name for the script, and it runs fine when I navigate directly to the page. When I click "Save output to file", it outputs the html content of my application 'index.cfm' page.

Comment: And did it create the log file you wanted it to create?

Comment: No, it did not update the log file.

Comment: Is it protected by a login or is there some sort of redirection involved?

Comment: Ah, I was reading your comment a bit more closely.  You said it `outputs the HTML content of my application `index.cfm` page`. Some login, as @Ageax suggested, or some other type of error handling seems to be at work.

Comment: No, it's just a basic txt file. It is accessed fine when I run directly from the browser.

Comment: What I mean to say is that the log file that's generated when you click on the `Save output to file` on CFADMIN will sort of point you to a direction it wants you to go. Remember, a scheduled task has no application variables set, so if it needs to log in or something, it won't have that information. Try running `http://localhost:8000/source/update_status.cfm` in an incognito browser and see what happens.

Comment: Hm - that makes a lot of sense.But I just tried including my login credentials, and still get the same result.

Comment: What does running the URL on an incognito browser do?

Comment: I bounces me back to the application index page - which is why it seems like including my credentials in the scheduled task should have worked - but no-go.

Comment: What *kind* of credentials? IIRC, it only supports "basic" authentication.

Comment: Or, what might be happening, is that `onRequestStart` on your `Application.cfc`, it's looking for some login variable.  You could do 1 of 3 things: 1) adjust `onRequestStart` to exempt that URL, basically saying, if you're this URL, ignore this portion or 2) add an Application.cfc in the `source` directory with an empty `onRequestStart` portion. Or option 3, find out if there are other scheduled tasks in that run in that server and find out how that's set up.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had the cfm file in a protected directory, so it wasn't being seen. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What are you doing wrong?  Re-inventing the `<cflog>` wheel comes to mind.

Comment: @DanBracuk - That's not actually what I was trying to do. It was an easy example that I was using for testing. But thanks for your pointless sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that I had saved my module in a protected directory. Since the context is not logged, the administrator was not seeing it.

To resolve, I just moved my file to a public directory.